# A film with main female character called Kara (or Cara)

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a film that was definitely shown on TV in early 90s. It is most likely an American film, because that's where most films on Russian TV at the time came from - unless they were Russian.
I watched just the middle to the end of the film but I know the gist of the plot.

The main character is called Kara and in the beginning she is given an artifact of huge importance, which gives it's owner great power. She is given that by a friend (who is possibly in love with her), because her friend doesn't take the reponsibility of guarding this artifact too seriously. She loses / gives away the artifact and chaos and evil ensues.

And this bit I have seen. She and her friend are in a very dark space, which is like a funnel, no visibility, trying to crawl out to the top. She eventually manages it, her friend doesn't because he is weighed down by guilt for giving away the artifact.

Any clues on which film that might be? Thank you!

Comment: What time was the TV series. was a medieval ... ???

Answer (score 9):

As a huge comic book fan, the name Kara is pretty familiar, as that's the Kryptonian name of Superman's cousin, Supergirl.  In the 80's, [a *Supergirl* film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_%28film%29) was made, which I knew of, but have never watched.  The [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_%28film%29) of the plot states she pursues an object of great importance:

> Kara Zor-El (Helen Slater) lives in an isolated Kryptonian community called Argo City, in a pocket of trans-dimensional space. Zaltar (Peter O'Toole) allows Kara to see a unique and immensely powerful item known as the Omegahedron, which he has borrowed without the knowledge of the city government, and which powers the city. However, after a mishap, the Omegahedron is blown out into space. Much to the distress of her parents (Simon Ward and Mia Farrow), Kara follows it to Earth (undergoing a transformation into "Supergirl" in the process) in an effort to recover it and save the city.

Comment: Nostalgia Chick did a review of that film http://thatguywiththeglasses.com/videolinks/team-nchick/nostalgia-chick/36132-supergirl which contains a lot more information about the plot

Comment: Correct. The vertical funnel and the maelstrom scene also happen sort of like that.